# Java ExecutorService when to call shutdown()

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to Java multithreading. I'm using `ExecutorService` to download a bunch of web pages to analyze. Currently my approach is to submit all Callables and put the Future objects in a list in a loop, then call `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()`, finally I process the future list.
My question is in my case, is it OK to put `shutdown()` after filling up the future list like this? As `get()` of Future already blocks until the task is done, seems that I should instead call it when I finish processing all the futures.

Answer (score 1):

Note the javadoc of `shutdown()`

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no
>   additional effect if already shut down.

This is a clean stop. The submitted tasks will run until they are done. Since you also have `awaitTermination()` which

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown
>   request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted,
>   whichever happens first.

Your `Future#get()` method calls will return immediately (if the `awaitTermination()` didn't time out). There is no issue with what you are doing.

---

Make sure your tasks don't run forever.

Comment: Will there be a big performance difference between calling it before and after processing the futures? Since one blocks all tasks, while the other can process the result while downloading the rest pages.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. What blocks all tasks?

Comment: Sorry. I mean `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()` will wait for all the tasks to finish. But if I call them at the end, I can process one page and download the others at the same time using `Future#get()`.

Comment: @hsluo Where are you doing this processing?  Only call `shutdown()` when you want to stop accepting submitted tasks. Only call `awaitTermination()` when you want to block for a certain time while tasks terminate.

Comment: Actually that's what I should have asked. I don't know whether to process the pages after all the downloads terminate or right after submitted all the callables.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods

```
1. shutdown()
```

as @Sotirios said, thread will completes the current tasks but did not add any new task for execution. So the current tasks will run to finish

```
2. shutdownNow()
```

It suddenly terminates all the tasks.

So by using the `shutdown()` method you can check weather all tasks are finished or not and can wait until all tasks are finished.
To acheive what you want, you can use `isTerminated()` method in the infinite loop as

```
while(!isTerminated());
```

So when all the finished next sequential action will be taken.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point using a thread *pool* if you shut it down after you've used it. It's designed to allow you to reuse the threads.

Instead, put the the `Executor` in a static field (or better, inject it with a DI framework like Spring). Then use `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>)`, which blocks until *all* the tasks you submitted have completed.